# ActionScript3: removeEventListener with function parameter

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, flash-cc

how can i remove `EventListener` from `MovieClip` in actionscript? Below is my sample code.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
var color: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
color.color = 0x00CC66;
colorChange_mc.buttonMode = true;
colorChange_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, changeColor(color));
colorChange_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, changeColorToNormal);

function changeColor(color: ColorTransform): Function {
    return function (e: MouseEvent): void {

        colorChange_mc.transform.colorTransform = color;
      }
 }

 function changeColorToNormal(e: MouseEvent): void {
      var color: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
      color.color = 0x000033;
       colorChange_mc.transform.colorTransform = color;
 }


  changer_mc.buttonMode = true;
  changer_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, removeEvent);
  function removeEvent(e: MouseEvent): void {
       colorChange_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,      changeColor(color));

  }
```

I created two `MovieClip`s on the `stage` , colorChange_mc has two `EventListener`s one for `mouseDown` and one for `mouseOut`. When change_mc button is pressed I want to remove one of the `EventListener`. I was able to remove `EventListener` without passing parameter to  changeColor function. But in my real class this parameter plays crucial role.

Comment: everything you are trying to do would be very easy if using classes. Your colorChange_mc could be instance of a class and handle everything internally without having to go through all those ugly hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class-var instead - one you have already in your code. To keep straight I created a second `ColorTransform` as a class-var - `normalColor`

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;    
var color: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
color.color = 0x00CC66;
var normalColor: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
normalColor.color = 0x000033;
colorChange_mc.buttonMode = true;
colorChange_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, changeColor);
colorChange_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, changeColorToNormal);

function changeColor(e:MouseEvent): void{

    colorChange_mc.transform.colorTransform = color;

}

function changeColorToNormal(e:MouseEvent): void {

    colorChange_mc.transform.colorTransform = normalColor;
}


changer_mc.buttonMode = true;

changer_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, removeEvent);
function removeEvent(e:MouseEvent): void {
    colorChange_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,  changeColor);
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: Wrong. First, his code of adding an event listener is correct in terms of "it's working" - the expression `changeColor(color)` returns a function, which acts as an event listener. Second, your solution proposes *another* function-return instead of a proper event listener, because your function accepts wrong parameter set and returns weird type instead of `void`.

Comment: @Vesper: Thanks! Second: copy'n'paste fault. SRY. First: Right, but ;-) . IMHO it is not the way to program a mouselistener in a clean way. My code is working. So I dont understand downvoting. Greetings

Comment: That's better. A downvote, thankfully, is retractable if issues that led to downvoting were fixed.

Comment: Hello Andre, thank you for your answer. I posted this sample code as an example, but in my real project I have 30 buttons and each has its own swf file that will be visible. That is why parameter passing is imprtant for me in addEventListener function. In short I just want to remove that event which has a pramater.

Comment: Then you youd use a `dictionary`. With this you could refer from the clicked button to your 30 `ColorTransform`s.

Comment: I made a new answer with `dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in order to remove the listener, you have to identify the function that you originally passed to it. But you have no reference to the function, because it is anonymous and lives in the global scope.

Think object oriented. Put all the functionality of changing the color into a class. All you actually want to do is

- specify a color value
- be able to disable the whole thing again.

Add two methods to the class of `colorChange_mc` that let you do this:

```
public function set color(value:uint):void
```

and

```
 public function set disable(value:Boolean):void
```

Alternatively, you can `override` the `enabled` setter function to tie your logic to it, if this is something you desire.

This way you can refactor most of the code that currently bloats your main time line into the class.

Answer (score 0):

According to my first answer and your comment with new facts here is a solution for more buttons/colors  using a `Dictionary`...

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var normalColor: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
normalColor.color = 0x000033;
//button1-30 are the instancenames of your buttons
var initObj:Array=[{btn:button1, color:0xFFFFFF},
                   {btn:button2, color:0xFF0000},
                   {btn:button3, color:0x00FF00},
                    ... 
                   {btn:button30, color:0x000000},
                   ];

var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();


initButtons();

function initButtons():void
{
    for each (var item:Object in initObj)
    {
        var btn = item.btn;
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, changeColor);
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, changeColorToNormal);
        dict[btn] = {color:item.color};
    }
}

function changeColor(e:MouseEvent):void
{

    var btn:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    var color:uint = dict[btn].color;
    var cT:ColorTransform=new ColorTransform();
    cT.color = color;
    colorChange_mc.transform.colorTransform = cT;

}

function changeColorToNormal(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    colorChange_mc.transform.colorTransform = normalColor;
}
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. As I said before the code that i posted  above was just an example. Sorry if I asked unclear question. I solved my problem by disabling some specific buttons when colorChange button is pressed.

```
_userCardsButtons_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
_userCardsButtons_mc.mouseChildren = false;
_userCardsButtons_mc.buttonMode = false;
```

this code disabled event listeners that I added before.

Comment: No. It doesnt remove the listeners, it only avoids the MovieClip to fire MouseEvents. Your code will e.g. cause a ram-problem if you try to remove the MovieClips, cause the Listeners are already registrated... Better going deeper in understandig all the provided answers. There is all you need...

Comment: I meant by "disabled event listener" it stopped react to any events that were registered it solved my problem. I know that it is not removing eventListeners from that movieClip.